# Tikz plot 3D truss

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, structure

[image]

How to draw the space truss below? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

This is what I'd do:

1. First define all the coordinates. The `calc` library will be very helpful here.
2. Then draw the lines twice: first thick white lines and then thin blue lines over them. This way I hope to improve the visibility. Some of the white lines are not necessary, but it's easy to draw them all than look for which one we need and which one not. In this case I prefer this method to the `decorations` library.

The rest are a couple of `\foreach` sentences to avoid repeating code (I think I could have added some more but...), and literally to join the dots.

Caveats: I'm not entirely sure about the visibility and I probably missed a line or two, but you got the idea, I hope.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,perspective}

\tikzset
{
   blue line/.style={blue},
  white line/.style={ultra thick,white},
    blue dot/.style={circle,fill=blue,inner sep=0,minimum size=1mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,isometric view,rotate around z=-35]
  % coordinates
  \coordinate (V) at (0,0,12);
  \foreach[count=\j]\i in {N,W,S,E}
  {
    \coordinate (\i0) at (90*\j:0.75);
    \coordinate (\i6) at ($(0,0,7)+(90*\j:0.5)$);
    \foreach\y in {1,...,5}
      \coordinate (\i\y) at ($(\i0)!\y/6!(\i6)$);
    \foreach[count=\yy, evaluate=\yy as \yyy using int(\yy+6)]\y in {0.7,2.2,2.9}
      \coordinate (\i\yyy) at ($(\i6)+(0,0,\y)$);
    \foreach[count=\yy, evaluate=\yy as \yyy using int(\yy+9)]\y in {1,2}
      \coordinate (\i\yyy) at ($(V)!\y/3!(\i9)$);
    % base
    \foreach\ii in {0,90,180,270}% 0 not necessary for this view
      \draw[shift={($(90*\j:0.75)-(0,0,0.2)$)},fill=gray!50] (0,0,0.2) -- (\ii:0.3) -- (\ii+90:0.3) -- cycle;
  }
  \coordinate (SW6) at ($(0,0,7)  +(225:2)$) {};
  \coordinate (SW8) at ($(0,0,9.2)+(225:2)$) {};
  \coordinate (NE6) at ($(0,0,7)  + (45:2)$) {};
  % right arm (north east)
  \draw[white line] (N6) -- (NE6) -- (E6);
  \draw[white line] (N7) -- (NE6) -- (E7);
  \draw[blue  line] (N6) -- (NE6) -- (E6);
  \draw[blue  line] (N7) -- (NE6) -- (E7);
  % back (north)
  \foreach\y in {6,...,11}
  {% squares
    \draw[white line] (W\y) -- (N\y) -- (E\y);
    \draw[blue  line] (W\y) -- (N\y) -- (E\y);
  }
  \foreach[evaluate=\y as \yy using int(\y+1)]\y in {0,...,8,10}
  {
    \draw[white line]   (W\y)  -- (N\yy) -- (E\y);
    \draw[white line]   (W\yy) -- (N\y)  -- (E\yy);
    \draw[blue  line]   (W\y)  -- (N\yy) -- (E\y);
    \draw[blue  line]   (W\yy) -- (N\y)  -- (E\yy);
  }
  \foreach\y in {0,...,11}
    \node[blue  dot] at (N\y) {};
  \draw[blue line] (N0) -- (N6) -- (N9) -- (V);
  % front (south)
  \foreach\y in {6,...,11}
  {% squares
    \draw[white line] (W\y) -- (S\y) -- (E\y);
    \draw[blue  line] (W\y) -- (S\y) -- (E\y);
  }
  \foreach[evaluate=\y as \yy using int(\y+1)]\y in {0,...,8,10}
  {
    \draw[white line] (W\y)  -- (S\yy) -- (E\y);
    \draw[white line] (W\yy) -- (S\y)  -- (E\yy);
    \draw[blue  line] (W\y)  -- (S\yy) -- (E\y);
    \draw[blue  line] (W\yy) -- (S\y)  -- (E\yy);
  }
  \foreach\i in {W,S,E}
    \draw[blue line] (\i0) -- (\i6) -- (\i9) -- (V);
  % left arms (south west)
  \foreach[evaluate=\y as \yy using int(\y+1)]\y in {6,8}
  {
    \draw[white line] (S\y)  -- (SW\y) -- (W\y);
    \draw[white line] (S\yy) -- (SW\y) -- (W\y);
    \draw[blue  line] (S\y)  -- (SW\y) -- (W\y);
    \draw[blue  line] (S\yy) -- (SW\y) -- (W\yy);
  }
  \foreach\y in {0,...,11} \foreach\i in {W,S,E}
    \node[blue  dot] at (\i\y) {};
  \foreach\i in {SW6,SW8,NE6,V}
     \node[blue  dot] at (\i) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the picture (danger!!!, do not touch):

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It is what I want. Thanks again.